# C/C++ : Creating & Execute Batch

Tags: c++, windows, batch-file, shutdown

I am working on a little private project, a programm that lets me control when to shutdown my PC ( I already know there are a lot of tools out there, but I still want to programm it)

As of now I always used the command-line : shutdown -s -t [x] (x for the remaining seconds) in the command menu.

Now, my programm should calculate the remaining seconds itself, write it in a batch-file & execute the batch file.

I already got it all working, except the part where it should execute the batch.

It just opens up a command-windows where the line fo the batch is displayed in an endless loop (without actually executing the line, just printing it).

Even if I just create the batch-file and execute it with my mouse in the folder, it still doesn't execute the command line, just display it in an endless loop.

-

```
void create_batch(double sec){

ofstream batch;

batch.open("shutdown.bat", ios::out);
batch << "shutdown -s -t "<<sec;
batch.close();

}

int main (){

time_t now;
struct tm shut_down;
double seconds;

int hh;
int mm;

cout << "Enter hour you want to shutdown<hh>\t: ";
cin  >> hh;
cout << "Enter minute you want to shutdown<mm>\t: ";
cin  >> mm;

time(&now);  // get current time
shut_down = *localtime(&now); // set shutdown date to today

shut_down.tm_hour   = hh; 
shut_down.tm_min    = mm; 

seconds = difftime(mktime(&shut_down), now);

create_batch(seconds);

system("shutdown.bat");
}
```

Thanks for all the help in advance.

Comment: Why not just run the shutdown command and not write a batch file and run that?

Comment: Did you call your C++ program "shutdown.exe"? If so, that's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, what is in `shutdown.bat`? Make sure it really contains what you think.

Second, is the place where you are writing `shutdown.bat` in the PATH? If not, you'll either need to change the PATH or pass a full path to `system()`.

Third, .BAT files are supposed to be associated with CMD.EXE, but that can be changed. Make sure the association hasn't changed.

Fourth, I would think `system()` would use file associations, but it might not. (I haven't used that API on Windows). You can always say `system("CMD /C shutdown.bat");` to not have to worry about that aspect.